# Linq-to-SQL - take not working

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0

I have this code C# code in a WCF service:

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var members = from member in db.Stops_edited_smalls.Take(25)
                          where Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(member.Latitude) - curLatitude) < 0.05
                          && Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(member.Longitude) - curLongitude) < 0.05
                          select  member;
            return members.ToList();
        }
```

Having the :

```
  .Take(25)
```

as above, returns no retults. Why so? (it works fine without the .Take(25))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're taking the first 25 before the filtering on the where clause rather than after. None of those 25 records matches the where clause.

If you only want the first 25 results, you should move the call to Take():

```
var members = (from member in db.Stops_edited_smalls
              where Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(member.Latitude)
                  - curLatitutde) < 0.05
              && Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(member.Longitude)
                  - curLongitude) < 0.05
              select member).Take(25);
```

Comment: Ahh, perfect, thats the one! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As Justin says, you've got your `Take` in the wrong place. It's like saying "Find the first 25 words in the dictionary, and then filter out anything that doesn't begin with B." That's not how you find the first 25 words beginning with B. You probably just want:

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    var members = 
      from member in db.Stops_edited_smalls
      where Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(member.Latitude) - curLatitude) < 0.05
         && Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(member.Longitude) - curLongitude) < 0.05
      select member;

    return members.Take(25).ToList();
}
```

I prefer to put the `Take` call *separately* to the query expression, just for the sake of readability. Either will work though, and this *does* perform the "just the first 25 values" in the database, not locally.

Given that you only want the "first" 25 rows though, you should probably specify an ordering, e.g.

```
    var members = 
      from member in db.Stops_edited_smalls
      where Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(member.Latitude) - curLatitude) < 0.05
         && Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(member.Longitude) - curLongitude) < 0.05
      orderby member.Latitude
      select member;
```

... except using whatever property you really want to order by.

Comment: Ah! very interesting. Specially the bit that says "does perform the 'just the first 25 values' in the database, not locally." I wish I had known that before.